# Polymer global variables document may be wrong~

Tags: polymer

I'm new to polymer and now reading the document. But I'm confused about the following document:

```
(function() {
var values = {};

Polymer('app-globals', {
   ready: function() {
     for (var i = 0; i < this.attributes.length; ++i) {
       var attr = this.attributes[i];
       values[attr.nodeName] = attr.nodeValue;
     }
   }
});
})();
```

and then define the global variables like this:

`<app-globals firstName="Addy" lastName="Osmani"></app-globals>`

I've tried this way but I can't get any variables via app-globals, the `Value` is absolutely a local variable for it is not with a `this.` started, then how can I get the value via app-globals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a mistake in the documentation. I believe the intent is something like this:

```
<polymer-element name="app-globals" attributes="values">
  <script>
  (function() {
    var values = {};

    Polymer('app-globals', {
       ready: function() {
         // this bit at least is missing from the example
         this.values = values;
         // initialize values from attributes (note: strings only)
         for (var i = 0; i < this.attributes.length; ++i) {
           var attr = this.attributes[i];
           values[attr.nodeName] = attr.nodeValue;
         }
       }
    });
  })();
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

This way the data is available from any instance of `app-globals` as `instance.values`. I also published `values` so that you can bind to it.

```
... in some element template ...

<app-globals values="{{globals}}"></app-globals>
<h2>{{globals.header}}</h2>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's all cleared with `this.values = values`. I'm now got another question about published attributes, could you help me out?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25050120/confused-about-the-polymer-published-attributes