# confused about the polymer published attributes

Tags: polymer

I have dig to the ajax-core element of polymer, code like the follows works fine:

```
<core-ajax url="./ajax-test.txt" auto response="{{resp}}"></core-ajax>
<textarea value="{{resp}}"></textarea>
```

I can get the value from `{{resp}}` in this case. I have dig into the core-ajax source code and find out how it has been done:

1. make `response` a published attribute by setting `attributes="response ..."`
2. pass the ajax response to `this.response`

then I tried to build my own ajax component but it didn't worked, my ajax component code is:

```
Polymer('louis-ajax', {
  url: '',
  response: null,
  ready: function() {
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        this.response = xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
    }.bind(this);
    xmlhttp.open("GET",this.url,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
});
```

and my app code is this:

```
<louis-ajax url="http://polymer.snspay.cn/api/posts.json" response="{{response}}"></louis-ajax>
<span>We have got the ajax response as</span> : <input type='text' value="{{response}}" />
```

The result is the ajax request has been successfully done, but the value of input is "{{response}}", not the value of {{response}}, so I think there is something wrong about how I understanding the published attributes work, any helps? Thk.

Comment: I've figure it out by myself, the code must be in the `<template>` tag or it will not effect. My app code is not in any template.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know you said you figured it out, but for others coming to this page looking for a fully-working solution and explanation, here it is.

If you want data binding without having to create a custom element, you must put your code into a template with the `is` attribute set to `auto-binding`:

```
<template is="auto-binding">
  <core-ajax url="./ajax-test.txt" auto response="{{resp}}"></core-ajax>
  <textarea value="{{resp}}"></textarea>
</template>
```

Without this, Polymer won't know it needs to hook up the bindings in your html, and things like `{{resp}}` will be treated as text.

More detailed explanation can be found here: http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/databinding-advanced.html#autobinding