# Return simple value from polymer element?

Tags: javascript, polymer

I have successfully used core-ajax to pass a json object, but I want to write a custom element that can pass simple values.  Here is what I have, but it is not working.

**testOutput element**

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">
<polymer-element name="testOutput">
    <template>
        This doesn't do anything but output a value.
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer('testOutput', {
            response: "MyValue"
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

**testInput element**

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">
<polymer-element name="testInput" noscript attributes="input">
    <template>
        Here is the value from the other element:
        <h1>{{input}}</h1>
    </template>
</polymer-element>
```

**index.html**

```
<testOutput response="{{output}}"></testOutput>
<testInput input="{{output}}"></testInput>
```

**output**

> This doesn't do anything but output a value.
>
> Here is the value from the other element:

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25050120/723693

Comment: I should have noted that I am using an auto-binding template.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I simply had to publish the response variable in my output element.  You can do this by including it in the attributes or using the publish function.

```
<polymer-element name="testOutput" attributes="response">
```

or

```
    Polymer('testOutput', {
        publish: {
            response: "MyValue"
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your response should be a function.

```
Polymer('testOutput', {
        response: function() { return "MyValue" };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two ways to do it

**First way**

You need to create element where you want to get data:

```
<polymer-element name="first-element">
    <template>

    </template>
    <script>
    Polymer('first-element',{
        needPass: 'I am Passed'
    });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

After you need to get first element using querySelector and get data

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="second-element">
    <template>
        <style>
            :host{
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
        <h1>{{passed}}</h1>
    </template>
    <script>
    Polymer('second-element',{

        passed: '',
        ready: function(){

            var first_el = document.querySelector('first-element');
            this.passed = first_el.needPass;
        }
    });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Than call the elements into your index

```
<first-element></first-element>
<second-element></second-element>
```

**Second way**

Or you can call first element into your second element

first element:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="first-element" attributes="needPass">
    <template>

    </template>
    <script>
    Polymer('first-element',{
        needPass: 'I am Passed'
    });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

second element

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<link rel="import" href="first-element.html">

<polymer-element name="second-element">
    <template>
        <style>
            :host{
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
        <first-element needPass="{{needPass}}"></first-element>
        <h1>{{needPass}}</h1>
    </template>
    <script>
    Polymer('second-element',{
        ready: function(){
        }
    });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

and call into index only second element

I hope it help for you.

PS: I tested the code.